# Display a ProgressIndicator during an async loading of ListView items

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to display a  `ProgressIndicator` while performing an async background `ListView` item loading. The behaviour that I desire is:

1. Before start loading the `ListView` items, display a `ProgressIndicator` with a [indeterminate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) progress;
2. Asynchronously start loading the `ListView` items;
3. After the `ListView` items loading was finished, hide the `ProgressIndicator`.

Here is a [ssce](http://sscce.org/) of my unsuccessful attempt:

```
public class AsyncLoadingExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
        final ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final ProgressIndicator loadingIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        final Button button = new Button("Click me to start loading");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Async Loading Example");        

        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setItems(listItems);

        loadingIndicator.setVisible(false);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // I have hoped it whould start displaying the loading indicator (actually, at the end of this
                // method execution (EventHandler.handle(ActionEvent))
                loadingIndicator.setVisible(true); 

                // asynchronously loads the list view items
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000l); // just emulates some loading time

                            // populates the list view with dummy items
                            while (listItems.size() < 10) listItems.add("Item " + listItems.size());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally { 
                            loadingIndicator.setVisible(false);  // stop displaying the loading indicator
                        }                   
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        VBox root = VBoxBuilder.create()
            .children(
                StackPaneBuilder.create().children(listView, loadingIndicator).build(), 
                button                  
            )
            .build();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

In this example, the `ListView` items are loaded asynchronously. However, the  `ProgressIndicator` do not show up. Still in this example, if I omit all the `Platform.runLater(...)` code, the `ProgressIndicator` shows up, but, of course, the `ListView` items are not loaded.

Thus, how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, at the presented example, I am misusing the `Platform.runLater(...)` method, and consequently, the JavaFX Application Thread.

As mentioned at the [`Platform.runLater()` method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), this method

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future.

And, the JavaFX Application Thread is the thread from which the JavaFX scene graph can be accessed and modified by the developer code, visually reflecting the performed modifications.

Thus, when I start loading the `ListView` items from this thread, the UI becomes unresponsive (this is also stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm#sthref3)) until the loading is finished.

To solve the problem, the `ListView` items must be loaded at another thread and only the `ListView` update must be performed at Application Thread.

The above correction is presented in the following:

```
public class AsyncLoadingExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
        final ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final ProgressIndicator loadingIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        final Button button = new Button("Click me to start loading");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Async Loading Example");        

        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setItems(listItems);

        loadingIndicator.setVisible(false);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                final List<String> loadedItems = new LinkedList<String>();

                // clears the list items and start displaying the loading indicator at the Application Thread
                listItems.clear();
                loadingIndicator.setVisible(true); 

                // loads the items at another thread, asynchronously
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000l); // just emulates some loading time

                            // populates the list view with dummy items
                            while (loadedItems.size() < 10) loadedItems.add("Item " + loadedItems.size());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            // just updates the list view items at the
                            // Application Thread
                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listItems.addAll(loadedItems);
                                    loadingIndicator.setVisible(false); // stop displaying the loading indicator
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        VBox root = VBoxBuilder.create()
            .children(
                StackPaneBuilder.create().children(listView, loadingIndicator).build(), 
                button                  
            )
            .build();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Crferreira's self answer is perfectly fine.

This answer just demonstrates an alternate implementation that does not require the use of any [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) calls and instead uses a JavaFX [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) (as well as [Java 8 lambda syntax](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.*;

public class AsyncLoadingExample extends Application {
    private void loadItems(final ObservableList<String> listItems, final ProgressIndicator loadingIndicator) {
        if (loadingIndicator.isVisible()) {
            return;
        }

        // clears the list items and start displaying the loading indicator at the Application Thread
        listItems.clear();
        loadingIndicator.setVisible(true);

        // loads the items at another thread, asynchronously
        Task listLoader = new Task<List<String>>() {
            {
                setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> {
                    listItems.setAll(getValue());
                    loadingIndicator.setVisible(false); // stop displaying the loading indicator
                });

                setOnFailed(workerStateEvent -> getException().printStackTrace());
            }

            @Override
            protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
                final List<String> loadedItems = new LinkedList<>();

                Thread.sleep(2000l); // just emulates some loading time

                // populates the list view with dummy items
                while (loadedItems.size() < 10) {
                    loadedItems.add("Item " + loadedItems.size());
                }

                return loadedItems;
            }
        };

        Thread loadingThread = new Thread(listLoader, "list-loader");
        loadingThread.setDaemon(true);
        loadingThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        final ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final ProgressIndicator loadingIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        final Button button = new Button("Click me to start loading");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Async Loading Example");        

        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setItems(listItems);

        loadingIndicator.setVisible(false);

        button.setOnAction(event -> loadItems(listItems, loadingIndicator));

        VBox root = new VBox(
                new StackPane(
                        listView,
                        loadingIndicator
                ),
                button
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: It is a nice example of use of the `javafx.concurrent` package classes. Thanks!