# javafx rotating circle while loading

Tags: image, performance, javafx, loading

I have a method which loads some data and this can take a while, the problem is that you can still click on things and this might crash the program. So I am looking for a specific implementation of a loading-circle when you click on a button and the method starts.

Comment: If you have any questions or if it is still giving you trouble just comment and i will get back to you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18925353

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is setting the cursor to "Cursor.Wait" on the objects that are still loading

Here is the code for that:

```
node.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

If it still gives you trouble you can try temporarily disabling the nodes.

Here is the code for that:

```
node.setDisable(true);
```